# How to make second column blank if it matches the first?

Tags: r, for-loop

| newcolumn | newcolumn2 |
| --- | --- |
| Cell A | Cell A |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| Cell X | Cell X |

How to make this top example turn into what would be:

| newcolumn | newcolumn2 |
| --- | --- |
| Cell A | NA |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| Cell X | NA |

Also, is it possible to return a vector/list that could be iterated on? I'll probably be filling in the blanks not too soon after I can get past this with yall's help.

For example,

c(1,3)

I know this doesn't work due to the code asking, essentially, "do the entire columns match?".

I'm guessing it would require a for-loop to answer this question.

```
ifelse(all(DATA$newcolumn == DATA$newcolumn2), DATA$newcolumn2 = " ", DATA$newcolumn)
```

Comment: `DATA$newcolumn2 = ifelse(DATA$newcolumn2 == DATA$newcolumn, NA, DATA$newcolumn2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `` `==` `` in `Reduce`.

```
(df <- within(df, newcolumn2[Reduce(`==`, df)] <- NA))
#   newcolumn newcolumn2
# 1    Cell A       <NA>
# 2    Cell 3     Cell 4
# 3    Cell X       <NA>
```

---

*Data*

```
df <- structure(list(newcolumn = c("Cell A", "Cell 3", "Cell X"), newcolumn2 = c("Cell A", 
"Cell 4", "Cell X")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```